# what is the relationship of Salt, White Vinegar and Water to create 1 liter of Hypochlorous Acid

Tags: cleaning

What is the relationship of Salt, White Vinegar, and Water to create 1 liter of Hypochlorous Acid (for disinfecting and cleaning purposes), and how much time do I have to put it under a 9v battery induced electrolyzing process?

Comment: Don´t do that..

Comment: Vinegar and water do not make any chemical reaction. So they will not produce Hypochlorous acid. If you want to produce hypochlorous acid, you have to electrolyze salt alone,  without vinegar. The main point is not the tension (9 V), but it is the currant. And the currant depends upon the geometry : surface of electrodes, distance between electrodes and resistance of the solution. The duration of the electrolysis may be many hours. But it depends on the currant. Vinegar may be added at the end of the electrolysis.

Comment: The vinegar is added to the salt solution to raise the pH to shift the product equilibrium from sodium hypochlorite to hypochloric acid

Comment: Vinegar would lower the pH.

Comment: The action of a weak acid (even H2CO3, acetic acid, Vitamin C,...) are generally all stronger than HOCl and will displaced it from NaOCl. Best preparation reaction is CaCl2 + NaOCl  (Chlorine Bleach) + NaHCO3 (Baking Soda) creating HOCl, a precipitate of CaCO3 and Na+, Cl+ ions. Decant to separate out the CaCO3. Best stored cold and used within a day or two. Unstable, Cl2, Cl2O fumes...

Comment: This path is based on an old patent citing the action of NaHCO3 on Calcium hypochlorite (or the action of CO2 on aqueous hypochlorite). My version is used when Ca(OCl)2 is not available. You should dilute the solution with distilled water to increase its stability and do store cold. Expect chlorine fumes and will react with transition metal to further produce powerful bleaching (and disinfecting) hydroxyl radicals, *OH, capable of breaking down organics by extracting a H atom creating H2O.